# How to send custom signal to bash daemon process?

Tags: bash, daemon, signals

I have simple bash daemon running (with root privileges ) in background which suppose to do `action1` or/and `action2` when notified.

How do I notify it/send some kind of signal on which it will react?

I've tried scenarios with checking file change every 1 sec or more often, but that's kind of less-desirable solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can send signals to a process using the `kill` command. There is a range of standard signals as well as two user defined signals, which you can let your script handle whichever way you prefer. Here is how this could look in a script

```
#!/bin/bash

handler(){
    echo "Handler was called"
}

trap handler USR1

while sleep 1
do
    date
done
```

To send a signal to the script you first need to find the pid of the script and then use the `kill` command. It could look like this `kill -USR1 24962`.

Comment: thanks. Is `-USR1` something pre-defined or I could have anything in place of `-USR1` ?

Comment: @greenV You can get a list of the available signals with the command `kill -l`. It will show you both the number and name of each signal. The user defined signals are called `USR1` and `USR2`.

Comment: @kasperd that wont work as you might expect it to. When `sleep` becomes the foreground process, it looks like when using trap, bash internally queues the signals until the command finishes (although it does handle them when the signal arrives).
This has the effect of making the signal actually only get handled once the foreground command has finished.
In your case you end up waiting a second for the signal to get 'delivered' to the script. May not affect you depending on your use case, but something to note.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [kill](http://linux.die.net/man/1/kill) command to send a process a signal. In bash,  you can use the [trap](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_12_02.html) command to create a [signal handler](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/chap_12.html).

```
#!/bin/bash
# traptest.sh

trap "echo Booh!" SIGINT SIGTERM
echo "pid is $$"

while :         # This is the same as "while true".
do
        sleep 60    # This script is not really doing anything.
done
```